# Changing directory and to download file using bash script and also extract it

Tags: linux, loops, wget, tar, cd

I created a script to download file from `URL` and I want to download it in the specific directory but the problem is when its time in downloading it will not put to the directory given and also when extracting the file is in the given directory.

```
diskspace=$(df -h /var/ | sed '1d' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
bundle=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
allowed=10


if [ "${diskspace}" -gt "${allowed}" ]; then
        cd `/var/`
        wget $bundle
else
        echo "Not enough space to download the bundle"
        echo $output
    exit
fi
while true; do
                for f in *.tar.gz; do
                case $f in '*.tar.gz') exit 0;; esac
                tar zxf "$f"
                rm -v "$f"
                done
        done
```

Can Someone help me to this problem ? The thing that I want to happen is to download the file in the given directory and also extract it there. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick#Use_in_programming) around `/var/`, which probably results in an empty string, thus `cd`:ing to your home directory. Use apostrophies (`'/var/'`), double-quotes (`"/var/"`) or nothing at all (`/var/`).

Comment: As for debugging shell scripts in general: use `set -x` at the top of the script. `set -e` can be useful too.

Comment: why are you exiting out in the case statement, before extracting the tarball?

Comment: to extract all the tar  files ..